# Can't access this.setState

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client, apollo-server

I just implemented a working Apollo-client listener on a subscription. When a subscription is made, the code below can fetch and log it.

However, `this.setState` doesnt seem to work for some reason.. As when the subscription is fetched, the app throws `TypeError: this.setState is not a function`.

Can someone explain why?

```js
    componentDidMount() {
        const SUBSCRIBE_POST = gql`
        subscription{
        postAdded{
            id
            message
            type
            created
            customers_ID
            customer{id,firstName}
        }
        }
        `;
        let response = null
        const {client} = this.props
        client.subscribe({query: SUBSCRIBE_POST})
            .subscribe({
                next(data) {
                    response = data.data.postAdded
                    console.log(response)
                    this.setState({list: response})
                },
                error(err) {console.error('err', err);},
            })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before componentDidMount:

`const that = this;`

Then call later:

`that.setState();`

Read up on JavaScript “this” for an enlightened weekend. “You don’t know JavaScript yet” is an excellent read.

Also read up on react hooks.

Comment: grazie maestro!